# Average of rows in range Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet laid out like so:

```
+--id---+--val--+--timestamp--+
|  01   |  1.2  | 1340769912  |
|-------|-------|-------------|
|  02   |  1.6  | 1340769928  |
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I'd like to get the average of values within a range of 60 seconds, or a variance of 60 in the timestamp column. I've tried a bunch of stuff in terms of Excel formulae, etc. but I can't get it to work correctly. Is VBA the way to go?

EDIT: There's a lot of data and a lot of minutes, I need this formula to work if I copy it down a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have excel 2007 or later
`=AVERAGEIFS($B$1:$B$2,$C$1:$C$2,"<"&C1+60,$C$1:$C$2,">"&C1-60)`

for any version of excel:
`=AVERAGE(IF(AND($C$1:$C$2<C1+60,$C$1:$C$2>C1-60),$B$1:$B$2))` entered as an array formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula, rather than just ENTER

Comment: +1 I agree. I was on this track, then I thought that OP's time stamp may be date formatted, in which case this would be adding / subtracting 60 days. However, given the text in OP, I think this is spot on.

Comment: Tada, works for the first set. How do I use it on a mass scale (5000 entries) without changing the formula each time

Comment: $C$1:$C$XXXX define your time range, $B$1:$B$XXX define your values to average, and C1 defines the time you are looking at. Point those parts of the formula to whatever you are looking at, and you can copy/paste the formula to wherever you need to

Comment: @SeanCheshire It's not performing as I'd like. http://i.imgur.com/Keh2s.png Column E is the difference from the first time, so in theory the average number should be the same up until the E column hits 60, and it is not. I think the issue lies in the criteria statements: `&C1+60` and `&C1-60`. I'm no expert at this stuff but that's my logical assessment.

Comment: those give the range around the time point - with `+60` and `-60`, you are looking at up to 60 seconds away from the time in`C1`. If you want a different range, change the numbers after the + and -.

Comment: Perfect, understood. I had a different solution in mind but I like yours better because it smoothes the graph out a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is foolproof, but I think it's a good start, and VBA-free.

Picture didn't paste right, formula for Column D should be:

```
=ABS(TEXT($F$2,"hmmss")-TEXT(C2,"hmmss"))
```

[image]